# Django calculation based on form and database values

Tags: python, django

I started the project with django1.9 and python-3.4.4.
I have set up an app to track my energy, water and gas consumption. I started this project to get to know django and python better.

I have created a form where I have two fields. One for the Type of counter and one for the value.
Now I want to get the latest value from the database and do a simple calculation.

```
delta = value_db - value_form
```

**models.py**

```
class Verbraucher(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Typ = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Nummer = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return format(self.Typ)


class Daten(models.Model):
    Daten_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Verbraucher = models.ForeignKey(Verbraucher)
    Stand = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    Verbrauch = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    Zeitstempel = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    Updatestempel = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.Zeitstempel)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DatenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Daten
        fields = ['Verbraucher', 'Stand']
```

**views.py**

```
def dateneingabe(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = DatenForm()
        return render(request, 'verbrauch/eingabe.html', {'form': form})
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = DatenForm(request.POST)
        model = Daten()
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            Stand_db = Daten.objects.lastest(Verbraucher)
            instance.Verbrauch = do_calc(Stand - Stand_db)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I have tried various ways but none seem to work.
I hope that someone has an idea to help me out!
Thanks a lot up front!

**EDIT:**

The whole idea behind it ist to have a local website where you have a small form of two fields. One for type of the counter and one for the value it has today.
Afterwards I want to get the latest value from the database of this counter and subtract bot. Afterwards the calculated value should be inserted into the db.
I hope that helps?!

**EDIT2:**

I have played a little bit araound and found an error.
I get it, if I want to do the calculation.
`unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'Daten'`
The weird thing is that I have defined both as decimals in my models file...
This is the code (views.py after form = DatenForm(request.POST)):
`if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            Stand = form.cleaned_data['Stand']
            print(Stand)
            Stand_db = Daten.objects.latest('Stand')
            print(Stand_db)
            Verbrauch = (Stand - Stand_db)
            print(Verbrauch)
            instance.save()`

Comment: You need to be more descriptive of the problem. In what way does it "not work"? What does happen? are there any error logs?

Comment: I do not get an error. I submit the form form and nothing happens. I think it has something to do with this part: of the code
            Stand_db = Daten.objects.lastest(Verbraucher)
            instance.Verbrauch = do_calc(Stand - Stand_db)
It seems that the calculation is not taking place.

Comment: I think a problem you might have is that you're using 'lastest' instead of 'latest'

Comment: Also I don't know where you're getting Stand when you do Stand - Stand_db

Comment: First of all thank you for your support until now TomDunning and madprops.
@madprops you were right regarding 'latest'. I have fixed it in the code but still it is not working. I should get 'Stand' from the POST request.

Comment: You don't set Stand to be anything, if you want to get Stand from the form you must do something like form.cleaned_data['Stand'] . Check this doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#field-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all very much for your support and ideas!
I have managed to get the solution to my problem:

```
if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            Verbraucher_form = form.cleaned_data['Verbraucher']
            Stand_form = form.cleaned_data['Stand']
            Stand_db = Daten.objects.filter(Verbraucher=Verbraucher_form).values('Stand').order_by('-Stand')[0]
            Stand_db2 = decimal.Decimal(Stand_db['Stand'])
            instance.Verbrauch = (Stand_form - Stand_db2)
            instance.save()
```

Stand_db gives the last value in decimal of the chosen counter in a dictionary.
To get the actual value I had to seperate the key from the name.
Stand_db2 is doing that.

Finally I do the calculation and save the record.

Comment: thanks to you, forgiving me  -5 to my reputation after answering your question. guess i should delete it then.

Answer (score 0):

first of all the way arrange your view is not ok although it will work. The validated form data will be in the `form.cleaned_data` dictionary. This data will have been nicely converted into Python types for you. Fields such as IntegerField, DecimalField and FloatField convert values to a Python int, Decimal and float respectively.

```
from yourapp.model import Daten

def dateneingabe(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DatenForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            Stand_db = Daten.objects.lastest(Verbraucher)
            #you used Stand instead of instance.stand and since instance.stand is decimalfield is will be processed nicely 
            instance.Verbrauch = do_calc(instance.Stand - float(Stand_db))
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = DatenForm()
    return render(request, 'verbrauch/eingabe.html', {'form': form})
```

I hope it helps out

Comment: Thank you for your advise (view) and your idea. It helped me to get to my solution.

Comment: glad i could help. since it helped you, accept the answer @MFIC